# Compose IO Operations

Tags: haskell, io-monad

I am trying to compose some IO wrapped functions.

My current code (that works) is:

```hs
getUserHome :: IO String
getUserHome = do
    usr_id <- getRealUserID
    homeDirectory <$> getUserEntryForID usr_id
```

What I am looking for is a more convenient notation (one without using the `do`-keyword).

Without any of the Monadic salad I would just write

```hs
getUserHome = homeDirectory . getUserEntryForID . getRealUserID
```

I would guess there is an alternative operator for the `.` that respects the Monad ..?  But in all my searching, I have not found it.

---

I tried `<$>` but that does not seem to be what i want:

```
src/Main.hs:49:21: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘IO UserEntry’ with ‘UserEntry’
      Expected type: UserID -> UserEntry
        Actual type: UserID -> IO UserEntry
    • In the second argument of ‘(<$>)’, namely ‘getUserEntryForID’
      In the first argument of ‘(<$>)’, namely
        ‘homeDirectory <$> getUserEntryForID’
      In the expression:
        homeDirectory <$> getUserEntryForID <$> getRealUserID
   |
49 |   homeDirectory <$> getUserEntryForID  <$> getRealUserID -- usr_id
```

Comment: Direct answer to "I would guess there is an alternative operator for the `.` that respects the Monad ..?" -- there are two! They are called `(>=>)` and `(<=<)`, from `Control.Monad`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `>>=`, since Haskell eventually "desugars" the `do` block to this:

```
getUserHome :: IO String
getUserHome = getRealUserID >>= \usr_id -> homeDirectory <$> getUserEntryForID usr_id
```

this can be simplified with:

```
getUserHome :: IO String
getUserHome  = getRealUserID >>= fmap homeDirectory . getUserEntryForID
```

or:

```
getUserHome :: IO String
getUserHome  = getRealUserID >>= (homeDirectory <$>) . getUserEntryForID
```

Comment: Ah interesting i didn't know that about the do-block. Tho i do think the order of the functions is kinda counter intuitive ? Tho it is definitely the closest to what i asked

Comment: indeed `>>=` is left-to-right while `.` is right-to-left

Answer (score 6):

First always consider the types:

```
getRealUserID     ::              IO UserId
getUserEntryForID :: UserId    -> IO UserEntry
homeDirectory     :: UserEntry ->    String
```

Now you can:

1. apply `getRealUserID` with `getUserEntryForID`. That's a direct fit for

   ```
   (>>=) :: m  a      -> (a      -> m  b        ) -> m  b
   (>>=) :: IO UserId -> (UserId -> IO UserEntry) -> IO UserEntry
   ```

   Actually I'd prefer the flipped version if you want this to look like a composition chain, i.e.

   ```
   getUserEntryForID =<< getRealUserID :: IO UserEntry
   ```
2. Apply `homeDirectory` to this. That is in your case not monadic at all, so you need to lift it with `fmap` or `<$>`. Take operator precedence into account.

   ```
   fmap homeDirectory $ getUserEntryForID =<< getRealUserID
   homeDirectory <$> (getUserEntryForID =<< getRealUserID)
   ```

Because monads are associative, you can also do it the other way around:

1. Compose `homeDirectory` with `getUserEntryForID`. The latter is already a standard *Kleisli arrow*, and you can lift `homeDirectory` to a Kleisli too in order to use the Kleisli composition operator:

   ```
   pure . homeDirectory :: UserEntry -> IO String
   pure . homeDirectory <=< getUserEntryForID :: UserId -> IO String
   ```
2. Again apply that whole thing to `getRealUserID`:

   ```
   (pure . homeDirectory <=< getUserEntryForID) =<< getRealUserID
   ```

In fact you could also turn `getRealUserID` into a Kleisli arrow as well, with a dummy `()` argument. This style is rather uncommon in Haskell, but it has the advantage that the associativity of Kleisli composition becomes obvious in the same way it is obvious for normal function composition:

```
pure . homeDirectory <=< getUserEntryForID <=< const getRealUserID $ ()
```

Comment: I think the notiation `homeDirectory <$> (getUserEntryForID =<< getRealUserID)` is my favourite way of writing this, thanks !